# How do I obtain the row number from my value of interest?

Tags: r, row

Let's say I'm looking for a particular row that contain my value of interest.
How would I do this?
The row number, not the number of rows.

Comment: `which(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == value)))`.

Comment: Much faster: `which(rowSums(df == value) > 0)`.

Comment: what about if I'm trying to find the row with the lowest value?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of solving the problem.
They both return a *named vector* of row numbers where the `value` can be found. The vector's names are the `rownames`, if that attribute is set. In my examples a built in `data.frame` is used (`mtcars`), and objects of class `"data.frame"` always have `rownames`.

```
value <- 3.07

i1 <- which(apply(mtcars, 1, function(x) any(x == value)))
i1
# Merc 450SE  Merc 450SL Merc 450SLC 
#         12          13          14 

mtcars[i1, ]
#             mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Merc 450SE  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.4  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.73 17.6  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.78 18.0  0  0    3    3

i2 <- which(rowSums(mtcars == value) > 0)
i2
# Merc 450SE  Merc 450SL Merc 450SLC 
#         12          13          14 

mtcars[i2, ]
#             mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Merc 450SE  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.4  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.73 17.6  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.78 18.0  0  0    3    3
```

As for the minimum, this is done in 2 steps, first get the minima per row and then compare those values with the absolute minimum.

```
m <- apply(mtcars, 1, min)
i3 <- which(m == min(m))
```

Now test both methods of finding `value`, `rowSums` is clearly much faster.

```
df1 <- mtcars
for(i in 1:10) df1 <- rbind(df1, df1)

mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  apply = which(apply(df1, 1, function(x) any(x == value))),
  rowSums = which(rowSums(df1 == value) > 0)
)
print(mb, order = "median")
#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
# rowSums   4.518236   4.597322   5.946051   4.634891   5.073521  77.25742   100  a 
#   apply 121.714384 128.003106 133.782672 130.505399 134.455721 205.99438   100   b
```

Final clean up

```
rm(m, df1, mb)
```

Answer (score -4):

please try
rowSums(mtcars == value)